# Fork vs. thread system time

Tags: linux, bash, shell, c

I got the following logs:

**Program 1**:
Taken from a program executed 64 `fork` calls:

```
real 0m0.023s
user 0m0.068s
sys  0m0.008s
```

**Program 2**:
Taken from a program executed 64 `thread` calls:

```
real 0m0.613s
user 0m0.370s
sys  0m2.027s
```

I don't understand the difference between the system times.

Shouldn't Program 1 System time be **higher** then for Program 2 because of the context switching between the process?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. Does the system actually context switch to the child processes? That's not guaranteed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696959/can-the-order-of-execution-of-fork-be-determined

Comment: Do you mind pasting the programs in question?

Comment: You'd have to run the programs several dozen times and then look at the distributions of run times between the 2 different methods.

Comment: language matters here. Some languages have very poor threading implementations (eg perl).